# I am getting a syntax error while computing average number of friends in apache spark

Tags: pyspark

Recently I have started doing a course of Frank Kane namely Taming big data by apache spark using python.
In the line where I have to compute average number of friends, I am getting a syntax error. I cannot understand how to fix this error. Please refer the code below.FYI I m using python 3. I have highlighted the code having syntax error.Please help as I have got stuck here.

```
from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext


conf = SparkConf().setMaster("local").setAppName("AverageAge")
sc = SparkContext(conf = conf)

def parseline(line):
    fields =line.split(',')
    friend_age= int(fields[2])
    friends_number= int(fields[3])
    return (friend_age,friends_number)


lines = sc.textFile("file:///Sparkcourse/SparkCourse/fakefriends.csv")
rdd=lines.map(parseline)
making_keys=rdd.mapByValues(lambda x:(x,1)) 
totalsByAge=making_keys.reduceByKeys(lambda x,y: (x[0]+y[0],x[1]+y[1])
**averages_by_keys= totalsByAge.mapValues(lambda x: x[0] / x[1])**(Syntax Error)

results=averageByKeys.collect()
for result in results:
    print result
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the line above, you're missing a closing parenthesis.

Comment: Thank you. I have made the changes but still i am getting a syntax error.Please find the code below.

Comment: @AnujMahajan I can't see the changes you made, please edit your question to include the current code.
Also, syntax errors are not dependent on concrete values. You can (and should!) shorten your code dramatically. E.g. find out the type of `rdd` and assign a value to it directly. Then you can omit `parseline` and `lines` which probably don't cause the error.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I had made a syntax error including the one you pointed out.